# Get Custom List Inactive field in SuiteScript search

Tags: search, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, custom-lists

Can someone tell me if the **Inactive** field on a Custom List record can be used as Search Column in search.createColumn();

something like this:

```
search.createColumn({
        name: 'isinactive',
        join: 'custrecord_custlist_field'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to use a join to the custom list, but you may be able to get the list through a search and get the inactive field value like this...

var customlist_yourlistidSearchObj = search.create({

type: "customlist_yourlistid",

filters:

[

],

columns:

[

```
  search.createColumn({

     name: "name",
     sort: search.Sort.ASC

  }),
  search.createColumn({name: "scriptid"}),
  search.createColumn({name: "isinactive"})
```

]
});

var searchResultCount = customlist_yourlistidSearchObj.runPaged().count;

log.debug("customlist_yourlistidSearchObj result count",searchResultCount);

customlist_yourlistidSearchObjSearchObj.run().each(function(result){

// .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results

return true;
});

Comment: Yes, that would be the last resort if ever. Thanks